# send email only for log level python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, exception

There are several similar questions asked, but none I could find that specifically address this scenario.

In python, I have a class that uses a library that throws exceptions when there are errors or data it cant handle.

My class wraps the library, catches the exceptions and logs them using logger.

I want to email any exception that is raised to myself, but I do not want to get an email for every log entry.  That is to say, I only want to get email when something is logged with logger.exception("The Exception"), but not if logged with logger.info("Great things are happening")

As I understand it the SMTP handler would email all log entries to me.

Comment: Use different handlers? [Multiple handlers and formatters](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#multiple-handlers-and-formatters)

Comment: Do you want to *log* other levels also? Or do you only care about exceptions?

Comment: @wwii I want to log everything, but only send email for exceptions.

Comment: [Handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#handlers). Also see the cookbook link in the other comment.  Make a handler and set it for CRITICAL or ERROR, when handling an Exception log with the appropriate level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own logging filter, like so:

```py
import logging


class MessageFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return 'goodbye' in record.msg


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.addFilter(MessageFilter())
logger.addHandler(handler)


logger.error('hello world')
logger.error('goodbye moon')
```

which results in

```
goodbye moon
```

Just replace the message in `filter` with the one you want to match and attach it to your SMTPHandler.

Comment: Great.  Is there an easy way to check whether the "record" is an exception?

Comment: As mentioned in [LogRecord attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes), log records may have an `exc_info` field if they have captured an exception.